# Tor Browser Bundle - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - How To Launch [start-tor-browser]

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu, help

I am running the Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS, 64-bit (Desktop)
and now the (Tor Browser Bundle) Ver.3.6.2 refuses to run the 
shell-script or launch the start-tor-browser?

Comment: Tor.SE as well as other sites in the StackExchange network are thought as Q&A sites. This question is more of a guide. Could someone separate question and answer here? If not I'm tempted to delete it.

Comment: @JensKubieziel, Dear Jens, done.

Answer (score 4):

If you follow these steps below and done everything correctly,
then this will work like a charm!
This might also work on other versions of Ubuntu & TBB.

1. Download the latest (Tor Browser Bundle) from https://www.torproject.org/ and save it into the `Home` (Downloads) directory.
2. Create a new folder somewhere in the `Home` directory. Example: Documents and move the `tar.xz` package into the new folder.
3. Right click with the mouse arrow on the `tar.xz` package and choose: Extract here
4. Go back to the new extracted folder `tor-browser_en-US` and open it
5. Right click with the mouse arrow on top of the `start-tor-browser`. In the menu, Choose: Properties » Permissions and mark the 'Execute [X] Allow executing file as program' and hit the `Close` button.
6. Do not close down the folder! Move the mouse arrow to the very left top of your computer. Now you will be able to see a "Invisible" menu that says:

   File | Edit | View | Search | Tools | Documents | Help
7. Choose: Edit » Preferences » Behaviour Now mark the (Ask each time) square and hit the 'Close' button.

Now you are ready to go!

Off topic!

I've seen alot of people recommending others to install and run
“WebUpd8“ and other things like “Polipo“

Well, that's up to each one of you, however I wouldn't recommend
any third party software to run within the Tor network.
It is also said that the Tor Browser Bundle is more secure
to run, rather then installing other softwares like “Polipo“

Just a thought! enjoy your Toring!

Comment: dude your the best! I have been searching the net like crazy for a simple way to install tor on Ubuntu and have been overwhelmed by all the different advice. your tutorial works like a charm thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a great program on GitHub call the torbrowser-launcher. [(Here)](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) It will download and verify and install torbrowser for Ubuntu. I have not tried it in 14.04, but it should work. It requires a ppa to be installed, but it is the easiest way that I know of.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```